# Why is special relativity so special?

Tags: special-relativity, terminology

The title says it really. Why is [special relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) so special?

I'm just curious as to how and why the term 'special' came to describe the theory of relativity where gravitational forces are negligible. I guess there was a need to distinguish it somehow from general relativity, but it still seems a slightly strange choice. Can anyone shed any light on the history of this?

Are there any versions of relativity that aren't special?

Comment: Does [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134417/) answer your question?

Comment: Ok, so it's a special case of general relativity. Thanks, I hadn't seen that question.

Comment: I believe that the phrase "special relativity" was first used (by Einstein) in 1915 when he formulated the theory of general relativity. Before then it was just called *relativity*.