# How does Lorentz Contraction apply to the edge of a spinning disk and is π still constant?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

This may seem like a dumb question, as I'm not really a physicist, but here it goes.

So, π is the number of diameter distances required to equal the circumference of a 2D disk. Relativity tells us that the faster an object moves, the shorter length of the object.

My question is: if a disk is spinning with angular velocity of say, $c/2$, would the number π be affected or would it remain it's same old 3.14 for a rapidly spinning disk?

Along those lines, how does the Lorentz contraction interact with an object that has varying velocities from the outward edge, to the inward center?

Comment: I realize this does not respond to your main question, only to your choice of wording, but:  Up until recently, nine was the number of planets.  When Pluto was de-planetized, did the number nine change?

Comment: @WillO No, neither depend on the other. I realize what you're saying, so the answer is... π remains the same, even though the diameter and circumference may change? How does the edge contract relative to the diameter though?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155537/60080 possible duplicate

Comment: I do not believe you can answer this question without specifying how the disk got started spinning in the first place.   Consider two different points on the circumference.  Did they start spinning at the same time according to someone sitting on one of those points?  Or at the same time according to someone sitting in the "stationary" frame?  Those are going to have different implications for how the circumference is distorted according to various observers.

Comment: @WillO The question appears to assume the stationary frame, especially given no mention of sitting on the disc.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie:  I do not agree with you.  The question says that the disk is spinning, which does seem to mean that we're supposed to answer from the viewpoint of the stationary frame --- that much I agree with.  But that doesn't tell me exactly how the spinning commenced (and what it looked like from the stationary frame), and I'm not sure we can answer without knowing that.

Comment: @WillO Sorry Will, excuse my lack of understanding but... What exactly do you mean by, 'how the spinning commenced'?

Comment: @Kris:  See my earlier comment.

Comment: @Kris:  Was a force applied to a point on the circumference, so that that point accelerated and then the signal propagated around the disk?  Or were forces applied to all of the points on the circumference at the same time?  And if so, the same time according to whom?  Etc.

Comment: @WillO I see what you mean. Let's suppose this is a thought experiment. The disk is indestructible and is spun up by a theoretical drill. The angular velocity reaches c/2 and an outside observer is measuring the circumference.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8659/2451 and links therein. See also  [Ehrenfest paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["_Understanding the “$\pi$
” of a rotating disk_" (pse/q/121889)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121889/understanding-the-pi-of-a-rotating-disk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ehrenfest paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox) concerns the rotation of a "rigid" disc in the theory of relativity.