# Is there any connection between special relativity and general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Is there any connection between [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) and [general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity)? We know that gravity causes relativistic effects according to general relativity which car similar to special-relativity. so is there any connection between general relativity and special relativity?

Or any thing in the scientific literature which has attempted to unify the special and general relativity?

Comment: Related: [Separating the topics of general and special relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480401)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is special relativity a special case of general relativity, qualitatively?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q134417/)