# Resource regarding Metric Tensor in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, resource-recommendations

I am studying Special Relativity along with the tensor notation used there. I do not know General Relativity but I have heard that **Special Relativity is formulated in pseudo-flat space**. I am interested to know about this fact in a little more detail, especially about the form of the metric tensor in Special Relativity. I do not want to delve into too much mathematical rigor right now (which is necessary for studying General Relativity).

Is there any book or notes or other resource which might help me to just know a few preliminary or elementary things about the metric tensor in the light of Special Relativity in simpler and less rigorous terms?

I will be very thankful if someone helps me in this regard.

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia entry for special relativity, here you will find things at different level of mathematical rigor, including a discussion of the metric tensor.

Comment: [This might be of interest](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368655/what-is-the-connection-between-special-and-general-relativity/368672#368672) though possibly too basic.

Answer (score 1):

- For starters, I would definitely recommend Sean Carroll's lecture notes on General Relativity. This one covers Special Relativity and Flat Spacetime: https://preposterousuniverse.com/wp-content/uploads/grnotes-one.pdf

In case you find this too technical, you also have:

- You can always check out the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Minkowski_metric and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity)#Flat_spacetime
- A pretty nice explanation on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soThEALam8k
- If you want to explore the metric tensor as a whole (independent of SR), here is a good YouTube video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGgdUEpGH1Y