# Minkowski metric derivation

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor

Can we derive the Minkowski metric from the Einstein field equations? I am still feeling unclear about the general relativity.

Comment: Can you show that it satisfies them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing General Relativity to Special Relativity in limiting case](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18904/)

Answer (score 1):

“Derive the metric” is maybe not the best description of what we do. You can take any metric you want. Then you can put it into the Einstein field equations to determine the stress energy tensor that produces that metric.

In the case of the Minkowski metric $R^\rho{}_{\sigma\mu\nu}=0$. So $G_{\mu\nu}=0$ and therefore $T_{\mu\nu}=0$. So the Minkowski metric is a vacuum solution of general relativity.

Comment: Technically, we can also insert the Schwarzchild metric and see that it refers to $T_{\mu\nu}=Mc^2\delta(r)g_{\mu\nu}$ (or something), and then realise that the $M\to0$ limit of that is Minkowski metric. But I think what the OP wanted is a set of steps starting from $T_{\mu\nu}=0$ to derive that Minkowski metric is the solution.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent that is not possible because Minkowski is not the unique vacuum solution. (You need to add additional assumptions - namely, flat spacetime)

Comment: @Eletie then an answer to the OP might need to state the extra conditions / assumptions needed for that derivation.

Answer (score 1):

The Einstein field equations in vacuum (i.e. with $T_{\mu\nu}=0$
everywhere) are
$$R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu}=0. \tag{1}$$

Because the tensors in (1) are symmetric $4\times 4$ tensors, these are $10$ equations.
The $4$ [contracted Bianchi identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contracted_Bianchi_identities)
$$\nabla_\rho R^\rho{}_\mu=\frac{1}{2}\nabla_\mu R$$
reduce the number of independent equations from $10$ to $6$.
So we have only $6$ independent equations for the $10$ unknown $g_{\mu\nu}$.
Thus the general solution $g_{\mu\nu}$ is not unique,
but depends on $4$ arbitrary functions.

It is trivial to check that the flat Minkowski metric
in Cartesian coordinates $(ct,x,y,z)$
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1) \tag{2}$$
is a special solution of (1).
We can get more solutions by applying any coordinate transform
$(ct,x,y,z) \to (x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ to this.
For example, by transforming from Cartesian coordinates to
spherical coordinates $(ct,r,\theta,\phi)$ we get the metric
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(1,-1,-r^2,-r^2\sin^2\theta)$$
which is also a solution of (1).

The coordinate transforms are $4$ arbitrary functions.
From the reasoning above we know the most general solution
$g_{\mu\nu}$ depends on $4$ arbitrary functions.
So we can be sure, the flat Minkowski metric (2) and its
coordinate transforms are all the possible solutions.
And there are no other solutions besides these.